# Is there any way to deploy an update to a CRM workflow plugin without first removing all references to that plugin?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Whenever we deploy an update to our workflow plugin, our customers have to first remove all references to that plugin in CRM, then remove the plugin, then install the new version.  Is there anyway to do an in-place update of the plugin?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2):

If you increment the Major or Minor version of the plugin, you can't update the plugin dll, because CRM gives the following error: 'Plug-in assembly does not contain the required types or assembly content cannot be updated.'

You have two options:

- Don't increment the Major / Minor version
- Register a new assembly next to the current assembly. Now you have two versions of the plugin assembly. Update all steps of the 'old' assembly by changing the event handler to the event handler of the new plugin assembly. After updating all steps, delete the 'old' plugin assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't increment the Major / Minor version of the plugin dll.

Check out [this site](http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.com/2011/08/assembly-versioning-in-crm-2011.html) for more info: